# Ruby on rails getting article_id inside comments controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to get the article id to pass into the comments.article_id, I have looked all over - and can't find anything(I am fairly new so I doubt I know what I'm looking for) I have been trying for the last couple of hours to pass the articles id to the comments controller then set the comments.article_id to the article id. Here's my code at the moment:

ArticlesController:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
require 'comment'
def new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.user_id = current_user.id
if @article.save 
  flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
else
    flash[:danger] = "We could not create you're article!"
    render 'new'
end
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
end

private

   def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
   end

end
```

My comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def new

end

def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.article_id = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Successfully created comment"
        redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
    else
        debugger
        flash[:danger] = "Failed to create comment"
        redirect_to article_path(2)
    end
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:description)
end
end
```

and my show.html.erb for articles(because I am doing it all in there)

```
<h1 align="center">Title: <%= @article.title %></h1>

<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="user-img">
                <p class="created">Created By:</p>
                <%= gravatar_for @article.user, size: 150 %>
            </div>
            <div class="user-title">
                <%= link_to @article.user.username,  user_path(@article.user) %> <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h4 class="center description"><strong>Description:</strong></h4>
<hr />
    <%= simple_format(@article.description) %>
<div class="article-actions">
    <% if logged_in? && current_user == @article.user %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete this article', article_path(@article), method: :delete,
                                                                         data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this article?" },
                                                                         class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
    <%= link_to 'View all articles', articles_path, class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'View all articles', articles_path, class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<% @article.comment.each do |f| %>
<div id="commentBorder">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= f.description %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div align="center">
        <small>Created by <%= f.user.username %>,<br />
                    <%= time_ago_in_words(f.created_at) %>       ago</small></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@comment, :html => {class: "form", role: "forms"}, :url => article_comments_path(@article)) do |comm| %>

<%= comm.label :description %>
<%= comm.text_field :description %>

<%= comm.submit "Post comment" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Just to add I do have the article_id set somewhere:https://i.gyazo.com/fe49dcebbe75c006e95c7f44a9964865.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution!**

So playing around some more literally five minutes after this, inside my Comments controller, I changed `@comment.article_id = Article.find(params[:id])`
Into

```
@comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
```

This fixed it, I have a theory on how so correct me if I am wrong.
From this picture you can see we already have article_id as a parameter(https://i.gyazo.com/fe49dcebbe75c006e95c7f44a9964865.png)
By using params[:article_id] we reached and got the article_id parameter and assigned it to our @comment.article_id value.

Comment: Your understanding is accurate. What you have is a parameter containing the article Id. What you either want to do is set the @comment.article_id equal to this value, or set the @comment.article equal to the article with that id. The mistake you had been making was that you were trying to make @comment.article_id equal to an article (when it is meant to be an integer, presumably). If you encounter problems with Strong Parameters, you may have to say `@comment.article_id = Article.find(params[:article_id]).id' instead.

Comment: Your theory is correct, you're essentially just assigning the value to that field. Charlysisto's answer is safer though for the reason he mentioned. You wouldn't want to allow someone to assign the article association without first ensuring the article exists.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear about rails associations, you could also have done :

```
@comment.article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
```

This has the advantage of ensuring the `article` exists before setting it's id value to the `comment.article_id`